# How to run a previously compiled version (or a previous build) of an Xcode project in ios 10.0 simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8, xcode8-beta2

I'm trying to test one of my apps on ios 10. I have downloaded the Xcode 8 beta which ships with the ios 10.0 Simulator. However, as expected, Xcode 8 is throwing tons of errors on the libraries I'm using [like Alamofire] which is preventing me from building in Xcode 8, which I don't feel I need to worry about right now. I'm just looking for an easy way to run the last stable compiled version (which I can successfully build within Xcode 7 for ios 9.3). I am unable to trigger the ios 10.0 Simulator from my terminal via xcrun as I have used to achieve similar things in the past.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

**EDIT -- Solved**

I figured out a way to achieve what I was looking for, for those interested.

1. In Xcode7 go to Preferences > Locations > and change Command Line Tools to Xcode 8.0
2. In Terminal, type `xcrun simctl list` to see the available Simulators (ios 10.0 simulators should be available now).
3. Copy the UDID of the Simulator you want.
4. Make sure the normal Simulator app is not running, then run `open /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app --args -CurrentDeviceUDID <Copied UDID>`
5. After the desired Simulator is booted, run `xcrun simctl install booted <path to project .app file>` (the path to the .app file can be found in Xcode on the left pane, under your main project, under the folder "Products" copy the file path from the [project-name].app file located there)

This should install the app onto the desired Simulator. I did encounter some errors the first few times I tried this. I got around them by simply quitting the Simulator.app and trying again (Worked for me on the fourth try).

Comment: You should be able to change the syntax back to the old Swift. I don't know if it then allows you to build and run it on the new simulators.